# Replacing backward slash in python / pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, path

I am trying to replace some `\` characters with `/` in some `csv` files (because I'm moving from windows to linux and need to modify pathnames that are listed in the `.csv` files.).

I have this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 file = 'my_file.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(file)
 df = df.replace('\','/')
 df.to_csv(file)
```

but I get this error:

```
file "<ipython-input-29-9556415d69a6>", line 5
    df = df.replace('\','/')
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I can replace any other character but teh `\` causes problems, presumably because it is trying to interpret the string as a path?

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `df.replace('\\','/')` escape a backslash when you wan't to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using or referring a backslash in a string (`\`), it has to be escaped by another backslash:

```
>>> s = '\just some test\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> s = '\\just some test\\'
>>> s.replace('\\', '/')
'/just some test/'
```

[Python lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) - String literals

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.